# Access or import an Outlook 2003 .pst file without Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, import, pst

I have a 450 meg .pst file (MS Outlook 2003 backup file) saved from a PC before it crashed.

I would like to break it up into its components i.e.

1. Save attachments to folders on my PC
2. Paste text-emails into a word processor, etc.

But I don't want to buy MS Office Professional 2003 or later solely for importing the .pst into MS Outlook 2003+. Outlook Express cannot import .pst files, only Outlook “proper” can.

Is there some free email client out there, e.g. Thunderbird, that can import .pst files?

Or is there some other way to access the 450meg file?

Answer (score 2):

Try the free trial version of Office 2010 at

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/try/

Once you extract your info you can uninstall the trial.

Comment: Thanks all of you! I’ll have a look. I’m actually fine with doing it manually, I just want something to work from. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking to do this programatically... If you're using visual studio, you can install VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) to work with a .pst file... you'll need to have office installed, however you can install the trial version and work with your pst file without having to pay for the full license (just Office itself won't open when the trial runs out)

Comment: Thanks again... The following also looks like an option: http://lifehacker.com/340521/import-outlook-pst-files-into-thunderbird-with-pst-import

Answer (score 0):

Get a trial of Outlook 2010. Get a trial version of Acrobat Pro.

Connect your old `.pst` file and export everything to `.pdf` files (e.g. messages, attachments, et cetera).